# No content on single product page Woocommerce after update

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

After update an template I dont see single product page anymore (no content)
No body after all

I see in development mode under main content -->content:

Iv searched for this long text but I could not find the solution.

I dont understand whats happening. I use WPBAkery page plugin builder and latest woocommerce ( iv used different versions of woocommerce)

Comment: content:  woocommerce_get_product_schema DEPRECATED with NO altertative in 3.0.0

Comment: Check for any theme updates, if the site is running a premium commercial theme, which integrates with WooCommerce, it will have an update available to address any compatibility issues.

Comment: Thnx is fixed, Solution: delete all files in FTP and install clean the newest update wordpress/theme